# Wix installer- Change Combobox Value Based on radio button change

Tags: combobox, wix, windows-installer, installation, msi-gui

In the Below Code i tried to change Combo box value when we selecting Radiobutton , but it is not changing

```
<Control Id="radioButtonGroupBox1" Type="RadioButtonGroup" 
         Property="INSTALL_CUSTOMSCALE" Height="34" Width="64" X="48" Y="99">
        <RadioButtonGroup Property="INSTALL_CUSTOMSCALE">
            <RadioButton X="5" Y="2" Height="15" Width="56" 
                                Text="Custom" Value="Custom" />
            <RadioButton X="5" Y="18" Height="15" Width="56" 
                                Text="Scaleout" Value="Scaleout" />
        </RadioButtonGroup>
         <Publish Property="CUSTOM_OPTION" Value="Server1" ></Publish>      

 </Control>
<Control Id="cmbCustomOption" Type="ComboBox" Property="CUSTOM_OPTION" 
             Height="16" Width="166" X="116" Y="101" >
    <ComboBox Property="CUSTOM_OPTION">
        <ListItem Text="Select..." Value="Select..."   />
        <ListItem Text="Server1" Value="Server1" />
        <ListItem Text="Server2" Value="Server2" />
        <ListItem Text="Server3" Value="Server3" />
        <ListItem Text="Server4" Value="Server4" />
    </ComboBox>

</Control>
```

And Also how to set Combobox non editable(readonly)

Comment: For updating the combobox controls does this answer your question? - http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-combobox-listbox.html#combolist-twin-dialog

Answer (score 0):

To set combobox non editable just add "**ComboList = yes**"

```
<Control Id="cmbCustomOption" Type="ComboBox" Property="CUSTOM_OPTION" Height="16" 
          Width="166" X="116" Y="101" ComboList="yes">
          <ComboBox Property="CUSTOM_OPTION">
            <ListItem Text="Select..." Value="Select..."   />
            <ListItem Text="Server1" Value="Server1" />
            <ListItem Text="Server2" Value="Server2" />
            <ListItem Text="Server3" Value="Server3" />
            <ListItem Text="Server4" Value="Server4" />
          </ComboBox>
</Control>
```